# Airflow "concurrency" parameter in the dag not consistent

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am creating a dynamic dag with configurable number of executors.

"concurrency" parameter given in the dag not consistent, in that this is not always spawning that many number of parallel tasks.

Have the airflow.cfg as :

```
parallelism = 32

dag_concurrency = 16
```

Why is this not working as expected, or are there any other settings there I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

You could set concurrency when instantiate the dag:

`dag = DAG(dag_id, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None, max_active_runs=1, concurrency=1)`

Answer (score 0):

In Airflow to execute multiple concurrent tasks in a dag, you have to set concurrency while instantiating the dag and it should be more than one:

```
dag = DAG(dag_id=DAG_ID, default_args=default_args, max_active_runs=1,
concurrency=4, schedule_interval='@daily'
)
```

And also to run multiple tasks in a Dag you have to setup executor as  LocalExecutor/CeleryExecutor.